# Notification quit after call

Tags: python

I wrote a Python script to show a desktop notification if the price of bitcoin reaches $4,500, but the script will quit if the price is reached. How do I keep the script running?

Here is the code:

```
import time
import requests
import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import Notify

r = requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
r.json()
resp = r.json()

price = resp["bpi"]["USD"]["rate_float"]
top = 4200

if price > top :

# One time initialization of libnotify
Notify.init("Crypto Notify")

# Create the notification object
summary = "Crypto Alert!"
body = "BTC : $ %s" % (price)
notification = Notify.Notification.new(
    summary,
    body, # Optional
)

# Actually show on screen
notification.show()

else:
    while price < top :
        r =requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
        print price
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Move the `while` loop. If you want the script to run forever (unless manually interrupted), make it `while True:`.

Comment: So it would be : while True: 
                                    r  = ... 
?? I want the script to run forever and keep pushing notification after the price is reach, is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

So from what I see it seems that you scripts is written to execute in a single pass i.e. all statements will be excuted only once. So what is happening is your script waits for the condition of price greater then to be true and once it is true it executes the rest of script of IF block.

What you need is an loop that encapsulates the script and who's end condition will take long time to achieve kind of infinite loop but safer.

Also another approach you may try is keep the script in infinite loop and simply exit the script when you want using ctrl + c

Although its not very clean way to do it.

Sample code :

```
import time
import requests
import gi
gi.require_version('Notify', '0.7')
from gi.repository import Notify

while true :
    r = requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
    r.json()
    resp = r.json()

    price = resp["bpi"]["USD"]["rate_float"]
    top = 4200

    if price > top :

    # One time initialization of libnotify
    Notify.init("Crypto Notify")

    # Create the notification object
    summary = "Crypto Alert!"
    body = "BTC : $ %s" % (price)
    notification = Notify.Notification.new(summary,body)

    # Actually show on screen
    notification.show()

    else:
        r =requests.get("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json")
        print price
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: Something like the edit apologies if it doesn't work in one go since answering from airport so couldn't test.

Comment: Perfect ! It does work, I did something similar waiting for your answer ! But it's as "good" as yours thanks for the clarification !!